# How to set corner radius for an element inside xib file

Tags: swift, xib

I am unsure how to get an Image View that is inside a  .xib file to have rounded edges. I have put "layer.cornerRadius" into User Defined Runtime Attributes, but that does not work.

Comment: You also need to mask to bounds, e.g. `layer.masksToBounds: true`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `layer.maskToBounds = true` like:

[image]

Comment: layer.masksToBounds is best.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you need to set the "clips to bounds" property to make it work, but the simplest way is not to set it in key path via CoreGraphics but with the Clips To Bounds option in the attributes tab :
[image: Clips to bounds UIView]

Then, you can add your layer.cornerRadius in "Key Path" :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest `@IBDesignable` view:

- Add a framework target to your project for the “designables". Choose “File” » “New” » “Target...” » “Cocoa Touch Framework”.

  When naming that target, a common  convention is to use the name of your project plus the suffix “Kit”, e.g. if your app is “Foo”, then call the framework target “FooKit”.
- Add a designable view `UIView` subclass to that framework target:

  ```
  import UIKit

  @IBDesignable
  class RoundedCornerView: UIView {

      @IBInspectable
      var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
          set { layer.cornerRadius = newValue }
          get { return layer.cornerRadius     }
      }
  }
  ```

Now, when adding a view to a XIB, you can specify that view’s base class as `RoundedCornerView`, and you can then specify the corner radius right in IB:

[image]

Comment: Off topic but, when you're using `MyAppKit` Group for file `RoundedCornerView`, should I use this group also for files where I have extensions of `Int`, `String`, ...?