# Right toolbar can't show all of property in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

[image: right toolbar]

This is what I see when I click on a `UIView` in xib file in the right toolbar. I can't see some properties like border radius, corner, perhaps others.

Comment: Corner Radius & border are on `CALayer`, not `UIView`, you won't see them unless you write them in `Identity Inspector`/`User Defined Runtime Attributes`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set corner radius for an element inside xib file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055650/how-to-set-corner-radius-for-an-element-inside-xib-file)

Comment: @Larme Hmmm, So nearly, so now i need add the frame work into my project? Or add some thing?

Comment: I don't understand your new question in comments.

Comment: Hi @Larme, I know your recommend. It's not problem about my XCode version, it's just lack of frameword to support it